# Android with LibGDX get access to a file

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i have an issue to read android files with libGDX

**I'm using :**

- Lib GDX 1.9.11
- Android Studio 4.2
- Java 1.8.0_261
- Andoid Gradle 4.0.1
- Gradle 6.6
- Android SDK 30-3
- Android 8.1 x86_64

First, i've implemented permissions in the XML file :

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Second, i ask user to allow access to the storage :

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    while (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
    while (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

(At the beginning i've used **while** to re-ask user if he picked deny, but it doesn't work, i didn't check don't ask again but dialog box doesn't pop again)

It works correctly : https://i.stack.imgur.com/v57uG.png

To create folders and read/write files i'm using FileHandle :

```java
public static boolean createFolder(String path) {
    final FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local(path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```java
...
final FileHandle playerFile = Gdx.files.local("data/" + fileName + ".dat");
playerFile.writeString(content, false);
...
```

```java
...
final FileHandle playerFile = Gdx.files.local("data/" + fileName + ".dat");
if (!playerFile.exists())
    return null;
final Scanner reader = new Scanner(playerFile.file());
...
```

Problem is access to read / write is denied :

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:11): avc: denied { write } for comm=656374696F6E207072696D6172795D name="perfd" dev="dm-0" ino=7181 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:10): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=4438 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I've read this topic : [Cant write nor read to/from external storage with LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380746/cant-write-nor-read-to-from-external-storage-with-libgdx/44028465#44028465)

But i'm using **local** files so i don't know where it comes...

Thank you in advance :)