# Error writing file: screenshot.png (External)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to take a screenshot, but all this time I get an error, I tried all the methods that were suggested here on the site, I also wrote in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I tried to also use the methods: local(),getExternalStoragePath(),getLocalStoragePath()

here is one of the ways in which I am trying to write a file:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched() && !flag)
    {
        flag = true;
        try
        {
            byte[] pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), true);

            for (int i = 4; i < pixels.length; i += 4)
            {
                pixels[i - 1] = (byte) 255;
            }

            Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
            BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);
            FileHandle fh = Gdx.files.external("screenshot.png");
            PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
            System.out.println(fh.exists()); // return true
            scaner.scanFile(fh);
            pixmap.dispose();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i still get the error

```
W/System.err: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error writing file: screenshot.png (External)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.write(FileHandle.java:302)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PixmapIO$PNG.write(PixmapIO.java:222)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PixmapIO.writePNG(PixmapIO.java:67)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PixmapIO.writePNG(PixmapIO.java:79)
    at com.repress.game.Start.render(Start.java:130)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:494)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1553)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1253)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.write(FileHandle.java:298)
```

Comment: Do you have runtime permissions? See: [Cant write nor read to/from external storage with LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35380746/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will still answer my own question.
In order to grant the user permission to write and read the file, I check if the user has granted permission to external storage, and ask for permission.
Thanks to this guy:[HERE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/168512)

Answer (score 1):

you have to give runtime permission in your java class
call this function in oncreate method :
requestStoragePermission()

and define the belowmethods outside onCreate

//Requesting permission

```
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        return;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }
    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I don't quite understand the parameter: STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE, I don't have such a constant that the AndroidLauncher class could suggest, maybe I don't quite understand the Android specific code

Comment: @zackscript it is a random integer , just to identify the permission result :-                      private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

Comment: I had to give permissions in the application settings on the device itself, and it worked for me, also I cannot correctly call the requestStoragePermission () method in the onCreate () method, as I get a bunch of errors

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to take a picture of a view as a bitmap using this code:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
v.draw(c);
return b;
```

}

and then write in external storage.
Most important think that android changing our privacy policy in android 10.In this privacy policy you would not write data in external storage without permission.But don't worry,add this tag in your manifest file

```
requestlegacyexternalstorage="true"
```